# Handle workbook Open Event of 1 Macro workbook from another macro workbook in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Respected Experts, Below is My Workbook_Open event code which is available in the Module of workbook Name **"Book1"**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

i = MsgBox("Please confirm to refresh", vbYesNo)

End Sub
```

I just want to select the msgbox with "Yes" of above Workbook_Open event via workbook Name **"Book2"** Macro File.Kindly suggest VBA code which handle **"Book1"** Workbook_Open event from **"Book2"** Macro codes.

Comment: The Workbook_Open event procedure is `Private`. Therefore it can't be called from another workbook. However, you can create a `Public` procedure, by any valid name you choose, placed in a standard code module (not `ThisWorkbook`) which you might call from another workbook. On the other hand, you can use the Open event of Book2 to open Book1, in which case Book1's open event procedure will fire.

Comment: @Variatus Basically I have more then 30 Macro Workbooks which has Workbook_Open event codings to refresh that workbooks. Is there any way that macro will automatically select 'Yes' of each Msgbox. OR is there any code which automatically select 'Yes' from MsgBox in same Workbook_Open event procedure.

Comment: No. Once the code runs user input is required. You would have to modify the event procedures themselves. As an alternative you might program `Application.EnableEvents = False` somewhere. In that case the Open events wouldn't fire at all, but neither would any other events in any of your workbooks.

Comment: @Variatus Thanks can you please check my another question as well i.e. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110082/how-to-drag-and-drop-in-vba-with-html-dom-codes) beacuse i have still not get any solution on the same.